# How to repeat title rows from page 2 when printing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a lot of data that i want to print.
I want to repeat some rows as title rows but do not want it to appear in first page.

Title rows will be always from the fifth row to the seventh row of my selection not the page.

So I tried this code and did not succeed.

```
Sub printonlyselection()
    Dim lPages As Long
    lPages = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        Selection.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
        .PrintTitleRows = Selection.Rows("5:7")
        Selection.PrintOut From:=2, To:=lPages
        .PrintTitleRows = ""
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is very easy but didn't see it clearly 
it will be a slight change into code 
i have already these rows repeated all over the file so i will fix just three rows
the code will print the first page without any repeated rows as headers
and then will print from page 2 to last page with those fixed rows then remove them again from headers

```
Sub printonlyselection()
 Dim lPages As Long
 lPages = Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("GET.DOCUMENT(50)")
   With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    Selection.PrintOut From:=1, To:=1
    .PrintTitleRows = "$5:$7"
    Selection.PrintOut From:=2, To:=lPages
    .PrintTitleRows = ""
   End With
End Sub
```